# Django Pagination + Regroup

Tags: python, django, pagination

So I'm working on a list view for one of my models and I want to display them by group like:

```
Group 1
  - Item
  - Item

Group 2
  - Item

 Group 3
  - Item
  - Item
  - Item
```

That's easy enough to do with `regroup` tag in Django, no problem there. But what if I want to paginate the queryset? Unless each group has the exact same number of items (they don't), I'll run into problems if I just do the standard:

```
queryset = Model.objects.all()
paginate_by = 10
```

So I'm wondering if there's anyway to paginate by group, or is Django's built in paginator totally incompatible with the `regroup` tag?

From my searching I get the feeling that I'd have to implement a custom pagination system to achieve this, but I couldn't find anything conclusive so thought I'd check here in case I'm missing something or possibly get some clean alternatives.